# Class to stateless function React

Tags: reactjs, this

I kind of rolled into React when stateless functions where popular so I never experienced the Class approach of it, which is bothering me now..

I'm not sure what this function does:

```
    var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
        "constant.false": 'false',
        "constant.true": 'true',
    }, "identifier", true);
```

Which is called as:

```
    this.$rules = {
        "start": [{
            token: "constant.numeric", // float
            regex: "[+-]?\\d+(?:(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\\d+)?)?\\b"
        }, {
            token: keywordMapper,
            regex: "[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*\\b"
        }, {
            token: "keyword.operator",
            regex: "\\+|\\-|\\/|\\/\\/|%|<@>|@>|<@|&|\\^|~|<|>|<=|=>|==|!=|<>|="
        }]
    };
```

I think it maps the input (what input :s) and returns either 'false', 'true' or 'identifier' as default.

But what if I want to use it within a stateless functional component? Since I can't use this in there.

Any help or explanation on how the 'this' function works is much appreciated.

Greetings,

edit:
The whole useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
const newCompleter = {
  getCompletions(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    callback(null, completions);
  },
};

const keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
  "constant.false": 'false',
  "constant.true": 'true',
}, "identifier", true);

const completionString = completions.map((x) => x.value).join('|');
const session = editor.current.editor.getSession();
session.setMode(`ace/mode/text`, () => {
  const rules = session.$mode.$highlightRules.getRules();
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(rules, 'start')) {
    rules.start = [
      {
        token: 'constant.numeric', // float
        regex: '[+-]?\\d+(?:(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\\d+)?)?\\b',
      },
      {
        token: keywordMapper(),
        regex: '[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*\\b',
      },
      {
        token: 'keyword.operator',
        regex:
          '\\+|\\-|\\/|\\/\\/|%|<@>|@>|<@|&|\\^|~|<|>|<=|=>|==|!=|<>|=',
      },
    ];
  }
  // }
  // force recreation of tokenizer
  session.$mode.$tokenizer = null;
  session.bgTokenizer.setTokenizer(session.$mode.getTokenizer());
  // force re-highlight whole document
  session.bgTokenizer.start(0);
});
// to extend existing
// addCompleter(myCompleter);
// to override all
setCompleters([newCompleter]);
  }, [completions]);
```

Original class component

```
ace.define("ace/mode/brms_highlight_rules", ["require", "exports", 

"module", "ace/lib/oop", "ace/mode/text_highlight_rules"], function(require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var oop = require("../lib/oop");
    var TextHighlightRules = require("./text_highlight_rules").TextHighlightRules;

    var BrmsHighlightRules = function() {

        var FalseBool = (
            "false"
        );

        var TrueBool = (
            "true"
        );

        var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
            "constant.false": 'false',
            "constant.true": 'true',
        }, "identifier", true);

        this.$rules = {
            "start": [{
                token: "constant.numeric", // float
                regex: "[+-]?\\d+(?:(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+-]?\\d+)?)?\\b"
            }, {
                token: keywordMapper,
                regex: "[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z0-9_$]*\\b"
            }, {
                token: "keyword.operator",
                regex: "\\+|\\-|\\/|\\/\\/|%|<@>|@>|<@|&|\\^|~|<|>|<=|=>|==|!=|<>|="
            }]
        };
        this.normalizeRules();
    };

    oop.inherits(BrmsHighlightRules, TextHighlightRules);

    exports.BrmsHighlightRules = BrmsHighlightRules;
});

ace.define("ace/mode/brms", ["require", "exports", "module", "ace/lib/oop", "ace/mode/text", "ace/mode/brms_highlight_rules"], function(require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var oop = require("../lib/oop");
    var TextMode = require("./text").Mode;
    var BrmsHighlightRules = require("./brms_highlight_rules").BrmsHighlightRules;

    var Mode = function() {
        this.HighlightRules = BrmsHighlightRules;
        this.$behaviour = this.$defaultBehaviour;
    };
    oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

    (function() {
        this.$id = "ace/mode/brms";
    }).call(Mode.prototype);

    exports.Mode = Mode;

});
(function() {
    ace.require(["ace/mode/brms"], function(m) {
        if (typeof module == "object" && typeof exports == "object" && module) {
            module.exports = m;
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: In functional components `this` is just undefined as functional components are more or less "instanceless". `var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({....})` is invoking `createKeywordMapper` and saving the result in `keyworkMapper` used later in the `$rules` object. Can you include your functional component attempt in your question, include any and all relevant code?

Comment: Hey Drew, thank you for your response. So is it correct that the createKeywordMapper isn't a function at all? Just a form of an object?

Comment: No, `createKeywordMapper` is quite obviously a function, it's invoked with several arguments and returns a value. What it returns appears to be a "token" string, or possibly an object with token parameters. We'd need to see its implementation to see for sure.

Comment: Alright, i've added the original code, which I want to translate to a functional component.

What do you mean that its invoked by several arguments? I only see it pop up once?

Comment: Is that code you are trying to convert to a React functional component even related to React? It looks decidedly very not React. I said ***invoked with several arguments***, i.e. `createKeywordMapper (arg0, arg1, arg2)`. Either way you'll need to import/define all the `this.XYZ` functions that belonged to the class, they won't need the `this` bit to be called.